# Ubuntu 16.04 hangs at purple screen during "try Ubuntu without installing"

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, 16.04

System Specs,
i5 6500, Nvidia GTX 970.

Installing Ubuntu on top of Windows 10

Tried with novoemode=0 and with nomodeset. Still no progress.

Answer (score 0):

there are no open source drivers for that graphics card so ubuntu can't use it on a fresh install (I have the same card so I know this works!).  Go into your BIOS and change your screen output from your GTX 970 to the internal graphics chip on your mohterboard then unplug the VGA from your graphics card and plug it into your motherboard.  Next install ubuntu, then install nvidia proprietary drivers.  Then go back into BIOS and and change your output back to your graphics card and plug VGA back into graphics card.  If I remember correctly you will need to leave the nomodeset and possibly disable the splash screen as well.